# ESpeakNG voice synthesiser(In PowerShell) not perceiving UTF-8 text

Tags: powershell, utf-8, speech-synthesis

I am trying to use the ccs/ka (Georgian) language to synthesize text of UTF-8 encoding:

```
გამარჯობა
```

I try to run:

```
espeak-ng -v ka გამარჯობა
```

but there is no sound played.

But when I create a file e.x. file.txt and write გამარჯობა inside that, it reads and plays without problem.

My ultimate goal is to run this without reading it from a file. I am trying to implement this in Python to use it on my project by using a wrapper from pip, or by using the subprocess module to run shell commands.

Tried:

```
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8
```

to let the UTF-8 be inputtable in powershell

Notable things:

```
$text = Get-Content .\file.txt
espeak-ng -v ka $text
```

If I run this in Powershell, it reads file and also plays the sound.
$text prints as `áƒ’áƒƒ›áƒƒ áƒ¯áƒ`. I am not sure of what encoding this is or how to convert this to a readable form. It would be enough for me to know how to convert Georgian text into this kind of text, so at least I'll be able to just write this whatever text and let that play.

The program also has the encoding argument

```
espeak-ng -b 1
```

This means that the text inputted will be in UTF-8 Format. Yet, when I do pass it, nothing changes.

Comment: `Get-Content .\file.txt -Encoding UTF8`

Comment: @JosefZ I did that, but no matter what, when I input UTF8 from the console, it just doesn't read. Tried even for Russian. No good

Comment: `print('გამარჯობა'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252','backslashreplace'))` returns `áƒ’áƒ\x90áƒ›áƒ\x90áƒ áƒ¯áƒ\x9dáƒ‘áƒ\x90`. That's why `$text` prints the same way (non-printable characters like `\x90` are _choked down_).  Which version of PowerShell do you run?

Comment: @JosefZ 5.1. I'm going to try that code you put and going to get the string with that, see what it does.

Comment: It worked even through the python wrapper. 
import espeakng
f = open("text.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
s = f.read().encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252', 'backslashreplace')
print(s)
sp = espeakng.Speaker()
sp.voice = 'ka+m6'
sp.say(s)

One thing to clear the decoded text to then let the synthesiser say the words correctly, it just reads slashes and stuff as actual Georgian words, so what kind of non printable characters would I have to filter out, or how to i do that it doesn't read them in the first place.

Comment: But it fails to read vowels ა,ე,ი,ო,უ. Everything else is read all properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIX:

Piping the text makes it work:

"გამარჯობა" | espeak-ng -v ka